# Serving local, pregenerated JSON to my javascript passenger, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, jquery, highcharts, passenger

I am pre-generating data points for graphing with highcharts.js, and storing them in my public folder.  I seem to be having issues in passing them efficiently to my JS code, so right now, I'm reading them in my view and pasting them into the function call within the HTML.  This doesn't feel right.  Ideally, I think I should be serving them from Apache, AJAX style, to my JS function, but the current method is what seemed to work...

generate_plot.js:

```
var generate_plot = function(str) {
  var t_test = str[3];
  var kdes = str[2];
  var new_vals = str[0];
  var old_vals = str[1];
  var chart_number = str[4] + 1;
....
```

In my view (*haml*) I'm doing:

```
...
 - txt = ['public', (comparison_path(params[:id]) + graph).split('/').uniq.delete_if{|a| a.empty? }].join('/')
      %div.bean{:id => "bean#{i+1}" }
      %div.time{:id => "time#{i+1}" }
      :javascript
        generate_plot(#{File.readlines(txt).first[0...-1] + ','+ i.to_s + ']'})
```

This ends up generating some pretty clunky and atrocious html.  I know there is a better way!

What is the proper way to serve local JSON data to the client for rendering?  I was trying to do this before, but my server didn't find the local JSON files directly, so I started using the Rails app to read them in.

Is there a reason my server wouldn't find the JSON?  Should I use AJAX to speed it up, or should I push it into the HTML (is it equally fast?)

Any direction here would be helpful, as I'm not ever sure what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have two different servers, one with highcharts, second with JSON, probably you come across cross-domain problem. So you can use JSONP, which reduce it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't cross-domain.  It is all local.